# Issue with Bake Sound to F Curves

Tags: audio, fcurves

Please help. Can’t find an answer anywhere. I’m baking the sound to f-curves to make this plant jump to music. The stem, flower, and pot each have their own shape keys which are each getting baked to f curves. Every one works except the stem. It only works to frame 250 and then it freezes. It isn’t a viewport issue because I ran a test render and it did the same thing. It shows it has f curves but it doesn’t work past a certain point.

Examples:
https://i.imgur.com/XRer4cS.mp4
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cktch.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you are using cloth or soft body simulation, check simulation start and end in the cache settings:

[image]

Comment: God bless you! I've been searching all over and couldn't figure out anything! That fixed it!